# Host is not allowed to connect to this mysql server when making a local connection

Tags: mysql, database, putty

When I try to connect with putty I get 'host is not allowed to connect to this mysql server'. Why is that happening? Host and client are on my machine.

When I connect with the command line it connects.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to change how your configuration is set up.

Comment out the skip-networking section within your MySQL config: `# skip-networking`, if you have `skip-networking` it will discard any TCP/IP connection which is likely why your failing.

Once you have enabled your TCP/IP connections you will need to grant permission to your user to connect from other machines:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO <username>@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';`

This will let username connect from any machine to your database with the appropriate password.

Comment: Works perfect. One thing to note I had to run FLUSH PRIVILEGES; to get it to update. Great answer tho.

Comment: Brilliant Answer. A one-stop solution. For me, it was "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '';

Comment: speciba! Just what I needed