# Failed to connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two computers connected on the lan and i want to simulate a client server type of configuration .So suppose i have pc1 acting as the server and pc2 as the client.I created a database on the pc1 and kept the registration form on the pc2 .so whenever i execute the registration script i get the following error.

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Host '192.168.2.6' is not allowed to
>   connect to this MySQL server

This is the registration code where i have replaced database host with the ip address of pc1(server) which is running xampp .

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', '192.168.2.7');//192.168.2.7 is the ip address of my server.
define('DB_NAME', 'hello');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
```

Do have i have to make any changes in mysql config file in xampp or if i have to make changes to the database host name.

Comment: Checkout this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731514/host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server-when-making-a-local-connecti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to provide access to all hosts through wildcard by using following query

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Refere to [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) for more info

Comment: how do i do this is xammp on windows

Comment: in phpmyadmin in `SQl` Tab PASTE the query and run

Comment: i got the following error Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.2.6' (using password: NO)

Comment: Try to login via the mysql command line and type the command there. To open this, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698914/how-can-i-access-the-mysql-command-line-with-xampp-for-windows

Comment: try this query on localhost not remotely. then you can use this query remotely

Comment: i did it on the server itself (localhost) still the same error

Comment: please check in `phpmyadmin` privliges that what rights you have for current user

Comment: please try by creating a new user follow the instructions https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql and then try to access with new user

Answer (score 1):

If the server is on your local computer, try using `localhost` as the ip address.

**To grant access to computer with ip: `192.168.2.7`:**
`GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'192.168.2.7'`
**To grant access to all computer no matter what their ip is:**
`GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'%'`

Comment: how do i do this is xammp on windows

Comment: You cant do it using xammp, since xammp is a webserver which installs mysql. Its not a mysql interface. To make it easier, try using mysqlWorkBench: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/